# JSON.stringify() and JSON2.stringify() difference?

Tags: javascript, json

I downloaded the JSON2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js and it does not have implementation for JSON2.stringify()

To be able to call a wcf service from jquery, I am using a helper class that uses JSON2.stringify()

What's the difference between the two and where do I get JSON2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you read the file you linked to it mentions

> This file creates a global JSON object
>   containing two methods: stringify
>       and parse.
>
> ```
> JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space) ...  
> JSON.parse(text, reviver) ..
> ```

So the object is JSON and not JSON2 ...

***[update]***

I assume you use the code from this article : [jQuery AJAX calls to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx)

If you take the time to read it all, he mentions that he is using a hacked version to handle the encoding he wants.. and points to a zip file with his version .. so look at the **JSON encoding** section in that article..